# Can an importin without any cargo pass through the NPC?

Tags: cell-biology, intracellular-transport

Can an importin (nuclear import receptor) without any cargo pass through the Nuclear Pore Complex (NPC)? If it can, wouldn't it be a waste of energy to have the 'unloaded' importin enter the nucleus and then binding to GTP?